# Angular in Internet Explorer

Tags: angular, internet-explorer

I'm starting to develop in angular. And I found out from a friend who already been on the job for a year, that he designs the program and design using chrome to check the looks and the layout of the components but he also needs to support internet explorer- and when you take something that works perfectly in chrome and try to use IE for it, components show differently all together and doesn't look as intended.
So, my question is: Is there some way to design from the start in order to be able to fit to both chrome and explorer? or some conversion from chrome to IE like there is for mobile devices with different screen sizes (websites adjust accordingly).
I would love to hear your opinions of whether or not it's possible and how, because i've searched and didn't quite find something addressing this issue.
Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to be aware of the version of your browser even if its IE or Chrome. If you really need IE for your audience normally your should develop for IE as your root,  on my experience the things you'll be doing on IE will work perfectly in Chrome.

Here are two tools I may use for this case:
https://caniuse.com/
https://html5test.com/

Angular 2+ uses Typescript in order to use ES6, so is a little more flexible for older versions. 
One of the main problems are the CSS in browser version, so is better for you to start from there, specially if you're beginning with Angular.

If you need further info, you should check https://fireship.io/ or his youtube videos about Angular. They are awesome to learn some great Angular tools.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the [Angular Browser support](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support), since Angular application use ES6/ES7 and some function might not support IE browser, if you want to run the application in IE browser, you could add the polyfills file and import the related packages. Please check the polyfills.ts file and uncomment the related import command for the IE browser.